# How to find out contention

Tags: rhel, performance, monitoring

I'm looking for an easy tool, to graphically show the amount of resources being used realtime. Something like htop but with disk IO, memory and network usage as well.

I tried ganglia and the fact that its not real time makes it annoying and the graphs aren't that great quality either.

Answer (score 1):

What about `atop`?

Launch with disk info

```
atop -d
```

Launch with memory info

```
atop -m
```

Launch with network info

```
atop -n
```

[this is the source](http://haydenjames.io/use-atop-linux-server-performance-analysis/) of the info provided

---

I just noticed the **graphically** requirement in your question. I use `conky` to monitor my local machine. As [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conky_%28software%29) describe it, it is an highly configurable system monitor.

You can configure it in order to display the data you get in graphs. But the quality of those graphs depends on your configuration : )

Answer (score 1):

unix way - is one tool that does only one thing, but does it the best. Some tools for network, some for i/o monitoring. start here [Best command line tools for linux performance monitoring](http://lintut.com/best-command-line-tools-for-linux-performance-monitring/) - the rewie and installation instructions